Python Barh Errorbar Plotting at beginning of interval
I have a question for errorbars with a pyplot.barh.
I want to include errorbars at the left side of the interval, not only on the right side( in the picture, the right side has errorbars, i want the same ones(same xerr) on the left side...
The code i used is following
plt.figure()
p = "Blue Colours Difference"
p1 = "Blue"
plt.title(f"{p}")
setdpi = 300
subList = [element for element in light_list if p1 in element.name]
for x in subList:
    print(x.name, x.LB, x.RB)
    
x = np.array([str(x.name) for x in subList])
LB = np.array([x.LB for x in subList])
RB = np.array([x.RB for x in subList])
colour = np.array([x.colour for x in subList])


plt.barh(x, RB-LB, color = colour, left = LB, xerr = 1, capsize = 2)

plt.xlabel("Wavelength "+ (r'$\lambda$')+ " [nm]")
plt.ylabel("Types of light")
plt.xlim(min(LB)-5,max(RB)+5)

plt.grid(True, axis = "x")
plt.savefig(f'pictures/{p}_diffraction_graph.png', dpi=setdpi)

plt.show()

I looked it up in the documentation and tried finding online resources regarding that problem

When you use the xerr keyword in barh it just passes the plotting of the error bar on to the errorbar function. So, for more control over the error bar positioning, just remove xerr from barh and directly use errorbar after plotting the bars, e.g.,
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

y = [1, 2]
width = [3, 4]
left = [1, 2]

err = 1

plt.barh(y, width, left=left)

# plot the error bars on the left
plt.errorbar(left, y, xerr=err, ls="none", marker=None, color="k", capsize=2)


